# when i run my code this error show up pls help: The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

```
using System;
{
    
}

namespace New_folder__2_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Hello World!);

           
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no brackets after 'using'

Double Quotes missing after 'World!'

```
 using System;

 namespace New_folder__2_ {
   class Program {
     static void Main(string[] args) {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: i marked it now i have this error you know how to fix it:Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types  code:      using System;

   class Program 
   {  
     static void Main() 
     {
         string stringvar ="Hello World!";

         console.writeLine(stringvar);

     }
   
 }